# Eclipse SVN commit an unupdated version?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm trying to commit an out of date version of a java project, but it won't let me without updating it.  I do not want to update it because the updated version is all messed up, so I checked out an older version...  Is there some way of creating a new project on the svn with it?  I can't get it to show up on our repository.  What option do I select when I right click the project and then select Team?

Answer (score 0):

Branch your working copy to the main repository, so you will have two working copies to refer. you will have access to both the versions so you can do the needful...[link for reference](http://codefez.com/creating-projects-in-subversion-trunk-tags-branches/)
see Branches, Tags and Trunk....